# Merge two consecutive rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two consecutive rows. If there is "SMN" in Pos column followed by B-PER then merge the two rows. If SMN is not followed by B-PER then don't merge

[image: 1]

This is the desired result that I want to achieve

[image: 2]

Comment: No images, please. By merge you mean concatenate both of them? After merging which value should be kept in `Pos` column `B-PER` or `SMN`. The question is very vague.

Comment: Yes. In other words concatenate. It could be any. Pos column is not important. what matters is names column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
       if df['Pos'][i] == 'B-PER' and df['Pos'][i-1] == 'SMN':
              newString = df['names'][i - 1].strip() + " " + df['names'][i].strip()
              df['Pos'][i-1] = newString
              df = df.drop(index=i)
```

This should work. Not sure the datatype of Arabic strings, so you might have to play with python datatypes to get this to work.